# How to list file of Remote system using python on local system

Tags: python-3.x, windows, operating-system

I have to **Search the specific file** on **Remote systems** using python script,  which is running from a local system.

the remote system are **Windows system.**

I have **tried WMI** to connect server, but i don't know how to **fetch directory structure** to local system using WMI.

If anyone have any other solution to search file on remote system using python, please share.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? This question is a bit broad as you've written it; sharing the code you've tried and the errors you're receiving can help us understand your problem. You might also consider [the WMI package from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/), and using [this technet blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-list-the-files-in-a-folder-and-all-its-subfolders/) as a loose guide to enumeration in WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest connecting to the remote system using SSH, for Python you can use the [Paramiko package](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko).